# How to optimize the upload of data onto the blockchain so that the miners will choose the transactions while paying relatively lower gas price?

Tags: transactions, mining, gas, gas-price, gas-limit

If I have 10 transactions that would fill 10 blocks worth of gas, would the transactions be more likely to be included in a block if I send 20 transactions that fill 1/2 of each block? What about 40 that fill 1/4?

How do the miners handle large transactions of this type? Can I do something as described above and pay a relatively low gasPrice? 10GWei? 5GWei?

Answer (score 1):

Miners are economically incentivized to sort the transactions by gas price descending, because it can increase their income. But they can sort and prioritize the transactions in whatever way they want, and use whatever algorithm they want. For this reason, I don't think you can make 100% foolproof predictions about this situation.

Statistically, I would imagine that the smaller the transaction, the more likely it is to be included sooner, because it leaves some room in the block for transactions with a higher gas price.

Depending on the exact sorting algorithm that miners use, if you are transmitting full-block-transactions, it may be necessary to use a high gas price to out-compete all the other transactions in the mempool.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely helps. Is there ever a case where there is a large transaction with low fees that miners will simply not include? Say 1/2 gas limit and gasPrice is 5 GWei (where avg gasPrice is 21GWei).

Comment: @blockchaindotsol I wouldn't know for sure, but it does seem plausible. I recommend just trying it and seeing what happens :-)

Comment: Sounds like an expensive test haha. Does Ropsten or Kovan behave similarly enough, in this sense, to accurately measure?